# how to see pictures of memory

Tags: android

I'm creating a "hiding picture" application which copies selected picture(s) from the gallery to application memory. It works perfectly and copies the image successfully form gallery to application memory location `/data/data/com.isummation.customgallery/files/`, and displays saved picture(s) in a `ListView`. However, I want to show images in a folder view, like this image:

[image]

What can I do to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        SELECT_PICTURE);



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                handlePhotoSelected();
            }
            break;
        } // SELECT_PICTURE

        } // switch
    }
```